# Fonts and encoding in windows live mail

Tags: windows, email, fonts, encoding, windows-live-mail

Sometimes I have non-english emails (arabic for example).
When I try to open them with windows live mail, it doesn't show them correctly..
for example such this:

> &1588;&1603;&1585;&1575;
>   &1610;&1575;&1605;&1575;&1606;

(I changed it a bit to show here as I want)

I had a look at options, there was encoding on

> arabic(windows)

but I didn't find anything else. When I open this mail on yahoo however, there is no problem.

What can I do?

Comment: You want a client to support HTML on non-HTML emails?

Comment: I want know if there is a solution for my problem with "windows live mail". I still want use it, I mean the pack of windows live essentials

Comment: Do you have the Arabic Language Pack installed?  It is available in Windows Update for Windows Vista and 7, and also can be downloaded from Microsoft's website for Windows 7 ([32-bit](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/updt/2009/08/windows6.1-kb972813-x86-ar-sa_210ccc96338a1ff683803eb4034e5f53d6d54c97.exe) and [64-bit](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/updt/2009/08/windows6.1-kb972813-x64-ar-sa_aaac936bd625c12b607dffea19fab8be9cfa28f6.exe)).  It can also be [installed from the Windows XP CD](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821080).

Comment: @Patches: thanks patches, but I have not problem with arabic in other places and also in this emails. I can see some words correctly, but some others are as I told, incorrect. I have arabic in my system with no problem.